# Can't open csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csproj

I'm trying to open the solution from the [image-comments project](https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments) that I pulled from Github. I get an error that the two .csproj files can't be opened. When I try to open them directly, I get the same error, plus the error that this project type is not supported. However, I can create a C# project in my version of VS (2010 Pro, with MS Visual C# 2010 showing as installed in the help dialog) and can open the csproj files I've created.

Other posts have made reference to finding missing versions of MVC, but I find no reference to this in the csproj (though I'm not positive I'm looking for the right thing.) Also, the pre-compiled version works, which suggests I've got most of the right stuff installed on my machine. The product version in the csproj is 10.0.xxxx, and I'm running up-to-date V10.

So, what do I look for next?

Comment: Do you have the full version of VS2010 or an Express edition?

Comment: It is an extensibility project.  You'll need to have the VS2010 SDK installed.  Download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2680).

Comment: @HansPassant - that solved it. However, the link you provided is to the pre-SP1 edition, which won't install and gives a useless message that a prerequisite is missing. The SP1 version is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21835)